# install zip file [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, zip, installation

I have been trying to figure out how to install .zip file in ubuntu (by the way i am trying to install VSCODE), after i extracted it, i dont find any:

1. configure file
2. no INSTALL

since those files that i know which could launch the installation, how can i do it without them?

here are what i have:

1. locales [folder]
2. resources [folder]
3. Code [executable file]
4. content_shell.pak
5. icudtl.dat
6. libnode.so
7. natives_blob.bin
8. snapshot_blob.bin

what can i do to install it? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First open a shell,
cd to the VSCODE folder,
run ./Code

Comment: it means that the application is not being installed right? morel like portable?

Comment: Correct, although you can install it to the system if you like.

Comment: that is what i mean, i can use it tho, but i want it to be installed for the long term confidential used

Comment: You might like [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/616363), since you are using ubuntu.